Hibernate replaces real where conditions with instructions like 1<>1
After moving from Hibernate 5 to Hibernate 6 (Spring Boot 2 -> 3) some of my queries stopped working.
And when I try to debug it I observer conditions like where 1=1 and 1<>1 and 1<>1 in my where clause instead of real column names.
I generate my queries using org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification and jakarta.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder.
public Specification<Thing> build(final @NonNull SearchParamsDto dto) {
        return ((root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Predicate conn = criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
            conn = criteriaBuilder.and(conn, criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("name"), dto.getName()));
            conn = criteriaBuilder.and(conn, criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("type"), dto.getType()));
            return query.where(conn).getRestriction();
        });
    }

which gives output like:
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.type from things t1 where 1=1 and 1<>1 and 1<>1
If I rollback to Hibernate 5 (Spring boot 2) printed sql is normal, let's say select t1.id, t1.name, t1.type from things t1 where t1.name=? and t1.type=?
Thing
@Entity
@Table(name="things")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Thing {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="type")
    private String type;
}

public class MyRepo extends SimpleJpaRepository<Thing, Long> { // ... }

And I execute query like this:
var dto = ...;
var spec = build(dto);
myRepo.findAll(spec, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC)); // I didn't override findAll method from SimpleJpaRepository


Spring Boot version is 3.2.5 (so spring boot jpa is 3.2.5 too). I use postgres:14-alpine for tests.
And I enabled these props to log sql:
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

So how to log full sql?
